# How can I set dropdownlist default values based on variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several pages linked together that I want to maintain drop down selections for.  I've seen a number of ways to do this with session values, etc, but I want to set the default value while still having the option of selecting other values.

Effectively, users will make selections on page 1 and then on page 2 they will use those same selections, but also potentially want to change their selections.  My thought was that I could load the selections into a table in SQL in page 1 and then in page 2 call that table and set the values as variables.  My question, then, is how I would set the default dropdown value to be a variable as opposed to a set value.

I am using VisualStudio2010 with ASP Webforms using C#.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I certainly wouldn't use a table for that. Your first guess to use sessions is probably right on. It seems like you have the impression that you can't change the session values, however...

Your pages should work exactly like you like:

Have the user select items on page 1, then store those values in the session.
Then on page two, set the values from the session as the default value in the drop down list. If they change their selection, simply update the session variable to the new value. 
Then you could repeat ad infinitum.

EDIT:
Examples,

Setting a session variable:

`Session["DropDownValue1"] = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;`

Setting the default valuie of a DropDown:

`DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = (int?)Session["DropDownValue1"] ?? 0;`

The `??` in the second example is a null coalescing operator. It means that if the object before it is null, then instead use the thing that is after it.

You will use both of those examples in the code-behind file `*.cs`

Then you can have a OnSelectedIndexChanged event to update your session variable on the second page, once the user changes it, if you like.

Add this attribute to your DropDownList in the `*.aspx` file:
`OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"`

With event handler code in your code-behind `*.cs` file:

```
  void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   Session["DropDownValue1"] = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: @BinaryTox1n - I'm pretty new to ASP.Net.  Could you give me code examples for that (especially declaring the session values and calling them as defaults) and tell me which file they go in (aspx, code behind)?  Thanks so much for your quick response!

Comment: @Kate I have updated the answer to provide some examples. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n - Thanks for the examples! A couple quick questions: What is the difference between selectedindex and selectedvalue (which I was using)? Also, would I put the code for setting the default value in both page 1 and page 2 since it will be updated on both pages? Also, where in the .cs does the setting default value code go?  I tried putting it in page_load and it gave me an error.  Is there a different event to put it in?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Kate sorry, there was a small error in the example, you need to cast the Session value to `(int)` when you set the `SelectedIndex`, I have updated the answer. It should work fine in the `Page_Load` method now. `SelectedIndex` is the positon of the selected item in the list, say index `1`. Selected value is the underlying value of that item, say `"NewUser"`. So you can see it would be hard to set the `SelectedValue` (.NET doesn't provide this functionality), but is very easy to store and set the `SelectedIndex` (like I showed above).

Comment: @BinaryTox1n - When I try that, I get the error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement"  I changed from == to = and then got and error on the ??.  I removed that piece and then it worked to save values from page 1 to page 2, but it still doesn't allow me to change the selection on page 2 and update the session value.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: @Kate I am not in a position to actually test the code at the moment, but I updated again to fix what I believe are the errors in the example. Could you describe your current problem in more detail, possibly providing an error message? -- edit, saw your answer. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

A database would work, but you could also use cookies or the Session.  What you would need to do is on the drop down list selectionchanged event, save those values into the Session (for example).  Then when the second page's page_load event fires, read those Session values in.

For a drop down list, you can set the selected value from either an object or a constant/value.

```
string myVal = Session["listChoice"];
lstChoices.SelectedValue = myVal;
```

Comment: @Thyamine - Thanks for your quick response!  Would the code you showed go in the code behind on the second page?  How do I declare the session variables initially?  And will those change if I change my selections in the dropdowns?  Thanks!

Comment: @Kate - You set the Session state by just saving an object there.  So on the first page you would write out 'Session["myKeyName"] = lstDropDown.SelectedValue; '  in the code behind page, and then what I wrote earlier in the second page.  The key you use is up to you, so it won't change based on the drop down name.

Comment: @Thyamine - I put 'Session["PAG"] = DdlPAG.SelectedValue;' in my page_load of Page 1 and 'if (Session["PAG"] !=null {DdlPAG.SelectedValue = Session["PAG"].ToString(); }' in my Page 2 Page_Load.  It works to save values from page 1 to page 2, but when I try to change the selection on page 2, it switches it back to the session variable.  Is there a way to have the selection on page 2 override and change the session variable?

Comment: @Kate - When you are doing the postback after the dropdown list is being changed you are setting it back to the Session.  In the Page_Load event, add  'if (!Page.IsPostBack()) { ... } ' around your code where you are reading the value from the session.  That way on postback's you don't lose the data, but on the initial page load you read from the session.

Comment: @Thyamine - When I try that code, it gives me the message "Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: Sorry, it shouldn't have the parenthesis in there:  !Page.IsPostBack

Answer (score 0):

You can store it the `Session` if you want to to just persist for the term of the `Session`.  If you want it to last longer, you could use cookies or you will need to store it in a database.

When you first load your `DropDownList` just check to see if you should default the value by looking for a stored default:

```
 // Initialize the DDL then check for the default value
 if (Session["DDL1Default"] != null)
 {
     ddl1.SelectedValue = Session["DDL1Default"].ToString();
 }
```

When the user selects a value and then navigates you should store it:

```
 // in some navigate event
 Session["DDL1Default"] =  ddl1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: This is working for me to save values from page 1 to page 2, but if I change the selection on page 2, how can I update that to be the new session value?  Thanks!

Comment: @Kate the same way you stored it originally. Just pull the value off the `DropDownList` and store it: `Session["DDL2Default"] = ddl2.SelectedValue;`  The `Session` is just a container, you can read and write to it from any page event.

Comment: When I try that, it sets the defaults to the first row in the dropdownlist rather than to what I actually selected.

Comment: @Kate I think your missing something about how it works.  You are just storing values in the `Session` object.  You need to read it out of the session and set the DDL to the correct selected value each time you rebuild or display it.  If you are getting the first one selected then you are either not setting the selected item correctly, setting the value before the DDL is built,or rebuilding the DDL after you have set the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Session variables.
In the `Page_Load`, set the drop down list's `SelectedValue`:

```
myDropDownList.SelectedValue = Session["myDropDownValue"].ToString();
```

**Edit**
Of course. Just update the variable in the `myDropDownList_OnSelectedChange()` event handler. You will need to make sure to put the other code, where you are setting the value from page 1 in the `Page_Load`, in an `if(!IsPostBack)` to prevent the dropdownlist from not updating.

Comment: Is it possible to have the selection on page 2 change and update the Session variable?  Right now it is only working in one direction, but I need to be able to change the selection on either page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone!  It is now working.  In case anyone else runs into this, here's what I ended up with:

Page 1 and Page 2 CodeBehind in Page_Load section:

```
       if (!Page.IsPostBack) { 
          if (Session["PAG"] != null) { 
              DdlPAG.SelectedValue = Session["PAG"].ToString(); } }
       Session["PAG"] = DdlPAG.SelectedValue;
```

Thanks again!